# In Oracle, is it possible to convert very large string (clob) separated by comma in to table with better performance

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to convert very large clob string in to table by comma delimiter.

Below function takes very long time. is there any fast function which returns table.

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION        UDF_STRSPLIT2 (
   P_STR     IN CLOB,
   P_DELIM   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ';' ,
   P_LIKE    IN INT DEFAULT 0
)
   RETURN MYTABLETYPE
AS
   L_STR    CLOB DEFAULT P_STR || P_DELIM ;
   L_N      NUMBER;
   L_DATA   MYTABLETYPE := MYTABLETYPE ();
BEGIN
   LOOP
      L_N := INSTR (L_STR, P_DELIM);
      EXIT WHEN (NVL (L_N, 0) = 0);
      L_DATA.EXTEND;
      L_DATA (L_DATA.COUNT) :=
         LTRIM (RTRIM (SUBSTR (L_STR, 1, L_N - 1)))
         || CASE WHEN P_LIKE = 0 THEN '' ELSE '%' END;
      L_STR := SUBSTR (L_STR, L_N + LENGTH (P_DELIM));
   END LOOP;

   RETURN L_DATA;
END;
```

Comment: what is your MYTABLETYPE? what happens when your substring exceeds 4k/32k?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speed this one up by an order of magnitude with DBMS_LOB instead of regular instr/substr:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DROPME$STRSPLIT2 (
   P_STR     IN CLOB,
   P_DELIM   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ';' ,
   P_LIKE    IN INT DEFAULT 0
)
   RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
AS
  L_DATA SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST ();
  L_STR  CLOB := P_STR || P_DELIM;  
  L_SUBSTR VARCHAR2(4000);
  L_STEP PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  L_THIS INT := 1;
  L_PREV INT := 0;
  L_END CHAR := CASE P_LIKE WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE '%' END;
BEGIN  
  LOOP
    L_STEP := L_STEP + 1;
    L_THIS := DBMS_LOB.INSTR(L_STR, P_DELIM, L_PREV + 1, 1);    
    EXIT WHEN L_THIS = 0;
    L_SUBSTR := 
    TRIM(
      DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(
        L_STR, 
        L_THIS - L_PREV - 1,
        L_PREV + 1
      )
    );        
    L_PREV := L_THIS;    
    L_DATA.EXTEND();
    L_DATA(L_STEP) := L_SUBSTR || L_END;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN L_DATA;
END;
```

Test case, process 60kb CLOB 10 times:

Your function:

```
18:15:50 SQL> l
  1  DECLARE
  2    VAL CLOB;
  3    RESULT SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  4  BEGIN
  5    SELECT C INTO VAL FROM DROPME$C;
  6    FOR I IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
  7      RESULT := DROPME$STRSPLIT1(VAL);
  8    END LOOP;
  9* END;
18:15:54 SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:11.56
```

Upgraded function:

```
18:17:12 SQL> l
  1  DECLARE
  2    VAL CLOB;
  3    RESULT SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  4  BEGIN
  5    SELECT C INTO VAL FROM DROPME$C;
  6    FOR I IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
  7      RESULT := DROPME$STRSPLIT2(VAL);
  8    END LOOP;
  9* END;
18:17:14 SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.87
```

Upd. to make sure they provide the same output:

```
18:20:08 SQL> l
  1  SELECT * FROM TABLE(
  2    DROPME$STRSPLIT1('a;b;c;d;f')
  3* )
18:20:10 SQL> /

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
a
b
c
d
f
```

and upgraded

```
18:20:16 SQL> l
  1  SELECT * FROM TABLE(
  2    DROPME$STRSPLIT2('a;b;c;d;f')
  3* )
18:20:20 SQL> /

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
a
b
c
d
f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple DBMS_LOB to manipulate CLOB

```
create or replace FUNCTION UDF_STRSPLIT2(P_STR   IN CLOB,
                                           P_DELIM IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ';',
                                           P_LIKE  IN INT DEFAULT 0)
    RETURN MYTABLETYPE AS
    L_STR  CLOB DEFAULT P_STR||P_DELIM;
    L_N    NUMBER;
    L_DATA MYTABLETYPE := MYTABLETYPE();  
    L_ST NUMBER:=1;
    L_ED NUMBER:=1;

  BEGIN
     IF LENGTH(L_STR)=1 --IF clob is empty
     THEN 
     RETURN L_DATA;
     END IF;
    LOOP
      L_DATA.EXTEND;  
      L_ED := (DBMS_LOB.INSTR(L_STR, P_DELIM, 1, L_DATA.COUNT)) - 1; --End postion
      L_DATA(L_DATA.COUNT) := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(L_STR,
                                              (L_ED - L_ST) + 1,
                                              L_ST);
      L_ST := (DBMS_LOB.INSTR(L_STR, P_DELIM, 1, L_DATA.COUNT)) + 1; --Start position
      EXIT WHEN L_DATA(L_DATA.COUNT) IS NULL;
    END LOOP;
    L_DATA.TRIM;
    RETURN L_DATA;
  END;
```

Comment: This one appeared to be way slower than OP's

Comment: replaced DBMS_LOB instead of REGEXP

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, then you can do this(in this case i used comma delimiter):

```
  select to_char(regexp_substr (cad , '[^,]+', 1, rownum))
  from clob_table
  connect by level <= regexp_count(cad,',');
```

In this example `clob_table` is a table that contains one row '1,2,3,4,5,6,7'.
Then if you want this as a table you can `create table as select`, using above query.