# filter ids in Clob Pl/Sql - oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have clob that contain ids that concatenated with comma (the length is more than 4000)
and I  want to create query that filter by the ids

like :

```
 select * from table where table.id in myClob
```

How can I do it??

Thank,

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP_SUBSTR which works on CLOB also

```
select * from table where table.id in 
(select distinct regexp_substr(myClob,'[^,]+',1,level) from table
 connect by regexp_substr(myClob,'[^,]+',1,level) is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that, maybe:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(C, '(^|,)' || 1 || '(,|$)');
--                                              ^
--                                  the id value you are looking for
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ec2e3/1

---

If you have space around the value, this slight change will be useful:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(C, '(^|,)\s*' || 1 || '\s*(,|$)');
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d31f/1

That being said, it is quite obvious that you shouldn't store multiple values as CSV in a column. This is (probably) error prone, and has (definitively) bad impact on performances, as you cannot use any index on them. If you really need to store multi-valued data in a column, maybe worth taking time to read about [Oracle's nested tables](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NESTED_TABLE).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp_like or regexp_substr to parse clob, however, chances are they will underperform. There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547107/in-oracle-is-it-possible-to-convert-very-large-string-clob-separated-by-comma) with a similar issue recently. What I would probably do is write a pipelined function that will transform your clob to a table of identifiers and then just join that table to your original query.

Pipelined function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION DROPME$STRSPLIT4 (
   P_STR     IN CLOB,
   P_DELIM   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ';'
)
   RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST PIPELINED
AS
  L_DATA SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST ();
  L_STR  CONSTANT CLOB := P_STR || P_DELIM;  
  L_SUBSTR VARCHAR2(4000);
  L_THIS INT;
  L_PREV INT := 0;  
BEGIN  
  LOOP
    L_THIS := DBMS_LOB.INSTR(L_STR, P_DELIM, L_PREV + 1, 1);    
    EXIT WHEN L_THIS = 0;
    L_SUBSTR := TRIM(
      DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(
        L_STR, 
        L_THIS - L_PREV - 1,
        L_PREV + 1
      )
    );        
    L_PREV := L_THIS;    
    PIPE ROW(L_SUBSTR);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Sample invocation:

```
11:27:55 SQL> L
  1  WITH T AS (
  2  SELECT
  3    COLUMN_VALUE AS ID
  4    FROM TABLE(
  5      DROPME$STRSPLIT4((SELECT C FROM DROPME$C))
  6    )
  7* ) SELECT * FROM T WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
11:27:57 SQL> /

ID
---------------------------------------------------
asdfa
asdasd asdfasd asdfads
asd asd fasd f
asd asd sa asdfa
asdasd asdfasd asdfads
asd asd fasd f
asd asd sa asdfa
asdasd asdfasd asdfads
asd asd fasd f
asd asd sa asdfa

10 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
```

`(SELECT C FROM DROPME$C)` is just a table of one cell with ~60kb junk semicolon-delimeted CLOB data I used for that aforementioned question:

```
11:38:36 SQL> SELECT SUBSTR(C, 1, 200) FROM DROPME$C;

SUBSTR(C,1,200)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
asdfa;asdasd asdfasd asdfads ; asd asd fasd f; asd asd sa asdfa;asdasd asdfasd a
sdfads ; asd asd fasd f; asd asd sa asdfa;asdasd asdfasd asdfads ; asd asd fasd
f; asd asd sa asdfa;asdasd asdfasd asdfa


Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
```